# Pros/Cons of In Order Binary Tree Traversal Using Recursion vs Using a Stack

Tags: c++, c, recursion, stack

I'm sorry if this is a trivial question. But I would like to know what are the advantages/disadvantages of using a recursive function to traverse a binary tree in order vs using an explicit stack.

- Which one will perform better?
- Which approach is more widely used in production code?

Answer (score 2):

Recursive method is easier to write but takes a lot of time in run time because every time it is called new variables are allocated & it takes much memory.

Non recursive methods take time to write but are very effective in the end.

I haven't worked at industry so I don't know which method is widely used but it should be non-recursive methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used recursive functions to traverse trees. Advantages its neater and quicker to do i find.

```
Which one will perform better?
```

From my understanding recursive will always be better performance wise. (or i was lead to believe by my professors)

```
Which approach is more widely used in production code?
```

All the good programmers have always used recursive traverse in my experience.